# Deleting file in Samba doesn't delete file?

Tags: samba

Why, when I delete some files in Samba, does it not delete them but instead merely change their filename from `filename.txt` to `._filename.txt`?

This is not the behaviour one would expect when "deleting" a file, so I'm wondering if there's an option I forgot to set somewhere in the samba config.

It does this to some files but not to others, I have not yet spotted a pattern to its choosiness.  There is a Ubuntu 12.04 machine and a Mac OS X machine which have write (and thus delete) capability, no Windows machines have write permission.

Comment: This might be because something is still trying to access/delete the file (over samba or locally).

Comment: Are all systems on the network Macs and Linux? If so, NFS would make more sense than Samba, which implements a Windows-centric protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Mac/OSX file is copied to a volume that doesn't support full HFS characteristics the extra information (resource fork, type & creator codes, etc) is stored in a second file with a name that starts with `._`. These files are invisible in OSX but usually are visible on other operating systems and tools. If you use a tool that doesn't know it needs to delete both files you will end up with an orphan file that starts with `._`.  The orphan `._` file will usually end up visible in OSX if the parent file is missing.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Do you happen to have any references I could read too?